# Consulta SQL unir dos tablas con JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando unir dos tablas para lograr el siguiente objetivo:

> Escribe una consulta que devuelva todos los almacenes que disponen de existencias para el > producto cuyo nombre es “Maleta de
> cuero” (existencias mayores que cero). Deben aparecer las siguientes
> columnas:
> [ “Telefono” | “Calle, Numero, CP” | “Existencias” ]

Esta es mi sentencia hasta ahora, pero me devuelve el resultado correcto, pero repetido varias veces las mismas filas, alguien sabe por qué?

```
SELECT al.telefono, al.dirCalle AS Calle, al.dirNum AS Numero, al.dirCP AS Codigo_Postal, ala.cantidad AS Existencias 
FROM almacen al, almacena ala JOIN almacen ON ala.idalmacen 
WHERE ala.idproducto=18 AND ala.cantidad>0;
```

Las tablas son las siguientes:

```
Almacen

idAlmacen, telefono, dirNum, dirLoc, dirProv, dirCalle, dirCP
1   952321297   1   Malaga  Malaga  C/Carreteria    29008
2   951422310   1   Coin    Malaga  C/Alamos    29010
3   952401615   1   Malaga  Malaga  C/Esparraguera  29018
```

Almacena:

```
idAlmacen, idProducto, cantidad
1   1   3
1   2   5
1   3   10
1   4   0
1   5   15
1   6   1
1   11  6
1   12  4
1   15  7
1   18  0
1   19  1
1   21  1
2   5   6
2   7   30
2   8   15
2   9   20
2   10  18
2   17  0
2   18  6
2   20  5
3   10  1
3   13  4
3   14  2
3   16  5
3   18  1
3   21  3
3   22  0
```

Producto:

```
idProducto, nombre,                 precio, tipo,   ISBN,           año, descrip, idEditorial
1           La Piramide Roja        15.95   LIBRO   9788484417552   2011           1
2           Cartas Cruzadas         19.85   LIBRO   9788426419804   2001           2
3           Cuentos para un año     59.5    LIBRO   9788492683666   2010           2
4           Mrs. Hemingway en Paris 20.42   LIBRO   9788420664538   1998           2
5           Cuarteto para un solista16.9    LIBRO   9788401340000   2005           1
6           El precio del trono     27.08   LIBRO   9788408107170   2005           2
7           Forro para libro        1.2     OTRO                
8           Portafolios             5.95    OTRO            Color negro 
9           Calculadora             19.9    OTRO                
10          Lapicero                2       OTRO                
11          Microsoft SQL Server Training   195.98  LIBRO   9788198856848   2011   1
12          OpenGL                  127.85  LIBRO   9788498856842   1997           1
13          Pajaro sin Vuelo        8.5 LIBRO   9788496871052   1999               1
14          Crimenes                15.5    LIBRO   9788420474984   2010           1
15          Federico Garcia Lorca   39.5    LIBRO   9788498383898   2001           2
16          Nueva gramática basica de la lengua española    13.5    LIBRO   97884269484 2000 1
17          Flexo                   14.95   OTRO                          Color azul    
18          Maleta de cuero         80.25   OTRO                
19          Kit de Rotrings         52.65   OTRO                          Del 0.2 en adelante   
20          Capitan America: la leyenda viviente    39.95   LIBRO   97884810032 2009        2
21          Maestros Marvel Jim Lee: X-Men  25  LIBRO   9788488242815   1983        2
22          Estuche                 3       OTRO
```

Comment: Añade un `GROUP BY al.idAlmacen, ala.idProducto` al final de tu consulta.

Comment: FROM almacen al, almacena ala JOIN almacen ON ala.idalmacen porque joineas dos vece alamacen, y no pones la condicion de join?

Comment: @A.Cedano aunque eso puede que funcione, esta mal...

Comment: Hola Juan podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles, gracias

Comment: Solo sirvió el comentario de A.Cedano, el resto de las respuestas no.

Answer (score 0):

El **JOIN** correcto sería:

```
SELECT 
    al.telefono, 
    al.dirCalle AS Calle, 
    al.dirNum AS Numero, 
    al.dirCP AS Codigo_Postal, 
    ala.cantidad AS Existencias 
FROM 
    almacen al, 
    almacena ala 
INNER JOIN 
    almacen ON ala.idAlmacen = al.idAlmacen
WHERE 
    ala.idProducto=18 
AND 
    ala.cantidad>0;
```

También te están pidiendo que tengas 3 columnas y no 5 como estás poniendo

```
SELECT 
    al.telefono AS Telefono, 
    CONCAT(al.dirCalle,', ',al.dirNum', 'al.dirCP) AS "Calle, Numero, CP", 
    ala.cantidad AS Existencias 
FROM 
    almacen al, 
    almacena ala 
INNER JOIN 
    almacen ON ala.idAlmacen = al.idAlmacen
WHERE 
    ala.idProducto=18 
AND 
    ala.cantidad>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.telefono, a.dirCalle, a.dirNum, a.dirCP, b.cantidad       
from Almacen a inner join Almacena b on a.idAlmacen = b.idAlmacen
where a.idAlmacen in ( 
                      select idAlmacen 
                      from Almacena
                      where idProducto = 18 and cantidad > 0
                     )
```

Primero se hace una **subconsulta** que nos va a devolver los registros **idAlmacen** de la **tabla Almacena** cuyo **idProducto** sea igual a **18** y su cantidad mayor que **0**. Sobre esta **subconsulta** hacemos una consulta general la cual va a juntar a las **tablas Almacen** y **Almacena** a través de la cláusula **inner join** y nos va a filtrar todos los **idAlmacen** de la **tabla Almacen** que se encuentran en la **subconsulta** antes explicada. Por último se seleccionan los campos deseados.